# "Unsupported architecture" while configuring SFML2 with cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, mingw, sfml

I'm trying to get SFML2 to compile under Windows 8 64-bit but it seems like cmake keeps returning this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Config.cmake:14 (message):
  Unsupported architecture
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (include)
```

Here is where it fails in the Config.cmake:

```
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")
    set(WINDOWS 1)

    # detect the architecture (note: this test won't work for cross-compilation)
    include(CheckTypeSize)
    check_type_size(void* SIZEOF_VOID_PTR)
    if("${SIZEOF_VOID_PTR}" STREQUAL "4")
        set(ARCH_32BITS 1)
    elseif("${SIZEOF_VOID_PTR}" STREQUAL "8")
        set(ARCH_64BITS 1)
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported architecture")
        return()
    endif()
```

As a side note, I'm using MinGW as the compiler and the configuration in cmake is to use 
"MinGW MakeFiles"

I have no clue why it is having a difficult time noticing my system architecture. Any pointers would be really helpful!

Thanks ^^

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am in the same exact boat as you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you do `message("SIZEOF_VOID_PTR: ${SIZEOF_VOID_PTR}")`, what does it print?